# spring not using RequestMappingHandlerMapping to map request

Tags: java, spring, tiles

I am creating a simple application on Spring MVC and tiles integration. 
Initially I was facing problems in loading the static content pages (like img).
So in order to serve the static pages, I included below line in the dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Now application is able to load the static pages. But somehow, the other requests were not able to reach the controller. On debugging, I found that "RequestMappingHandlerMapping" and "RequestMappingHandlerAdapter" was missing in the handlerMappings and handlerAdapters respectively. 
When I omit the resources mapping entry from the dispatcher-servlet.xml then my dynamic requests are getting served successfully. As a workaround, I have manually registered these two beans in the xml file.

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:resources location="/images/" mapping="/images/**"></mvc:resources>
    <beans:bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="handlerAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter"></beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.mds.presentation.controller"></context:component-scan>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"
        id="tilesViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**TestController**

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("login");
        mav.addObject("home","home");
        mav.addObject("buy","buy");
        mav.addObject("cart","cart");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

My curiosity is why spring is not able to register the appropriate handlers and adapters on its own when including **mvc:resources**. Is there something I am missing ?
I tried searching it in the spring docs and google however couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it makes sense to define those beans on your own.

Do you have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your XML configs ?

If not, try to add it to your XML file and remove:

```
<beans:bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
</beans:bean>
```

This should help for your requests to reach the controller.

Basically, `mvc:annotation-driven` tag sets you your Spring context to allow for dispatching requests to Controllers.

The tag will configure two beans `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`. Or maybe there are some new beans in a new version of Spring, but anyway that tag will configure them for you.

Comment: Bravo !!! This worked. It added the required two beans implicitly. Wondering how annotation setup was working when i didnt have mvc:resources and mvcannotation-driven in place.